# ArrayList creating card deck

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Over here I have some code regarding a carddeck that I'm trying to make in Java. The idea behind it is, to make 2 methods, to create a createDeck method, that returns an ArrayList  that also contains 52 different cards.

And randomizing them. so basically placing the list of cards provided as a parameter and placing them in random order. Could it be done using "Collections.shuffle(arrayList);"?

Any help would be appreciated

```
class Card
{
    public static final String[] SUIT = new String[]{"Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
    public static final String[] RANK = new String[]{"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"};

    public static ArrayList<Card> createDeck()
    {
    }

    private Integer suit;
    private Integer rank;

    public Card(Integer suit, Integer rank)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "'" + SUIT[this.suit] + " " + RANK[this.rank] + "'";
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        System.out.println(new Card(2, 6));
        System.out.println(new Card(3, 12));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, creating a list and then shuffling it should be fine. Could you clarify which bit you're having trouble with at the moment? I would suggest possibly using enums for the suit and maybe the rank, by the way.

Comment: Two nested loops... Outer one having Suites while inner one having Rank. And you have all 52 cards.

Comment: Since i'm really new when we're talking about ArrayLists, i'm kind of struggling on how to begin with it

Comment: [Enums tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enums.html) includes a  card example.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to basically iterate through all possible combinations of `SUIT` and `RANK`. You can do that by looping through them in nested way.

Make sure you add these combinations in `ArrayList` using `ArrayList.add(Object)` method. This will generate your deck.

Now, to randomize this deck you can use Java `Collections` library. Call random method with `Collections.shuffle(deck)` and whole deck will be shuffled.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Card {

    public static final String[] SUIT = new String[]{"Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
    public static final String[] RANK = new String[]{"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"};

    public static ArrayList<Card> createDeck() {

        ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<13; j++){
                deck.add(new Card(i, j));
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        return deck;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum to implement is. This would give you the possibility to assign values to the ranks. Another benefit would be, that you can easily generate a reduced deck, e.g. without cards 2, 3 and 4 or so.

I wrote a solution with internal classes, but you could pull them out as well.

```java
public class Cards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cards cards = new Cards();

        final List<Card> deck = cards.createDeck();
        Collections.shuffle(deck);

        deck.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private List<Card> createDeck() {
        final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
            for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
                deck.add(Card.of(suit, rank));
            }
        }
        return deck;
    }

    public enum Suit {
        Clubs,
        Spades,
        Diamonds,
        Hearts
    }

    public enum Rank {
        Ace("Ace"),
        King("King"),
        Queen("Queen"),
        Jack("Jack"),
        Ten("10"),
        Nine("9"),
        Eight("8"),
        Seven("7"),
        Six("6"),
        Five("5"),
        Four("4"),
        Three("3"),
        Two("2");

        private final String name;

        Rank(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static class Card {
        private final Suit suit;
        private final Rank rank;

        private Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
            this.suit = suit;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        public static Card of(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
            return new Card(suit, rank);
        }

        public Suit getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        public Rank getRank() {
            return rank;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return rank.getName() + " of " + suit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Rank.values()` instead of `EnumSet.allOf(Rank.class)` (same with `Suit`).  Additionally, this is going to give you a deck which contains an `Ace` _and_ a `One` for each `Suit`.